# Unintended double line spacing in CRichEditCtrl

Tags: winapi, mfc

I'm echoing the serial port input to a CRichEditCtrl, one char at a time as it arrives. The problem I've come across is that when I receive '\r' followed by '\n' I end up two lines further down page, not one. Debugging it a little I realise that sending "\r\n" results in (what I'd consider to be) the correct, single new line insertion, but sending '\r' and '\n' separately yields two new lines.

Simple example, where m_Output is obviously a rich edit control variable:

```
m_Output.SetSel(-1, -1);

m_Output.ReplaceSel(_T("X\r\n"));

m_Output.SetSel(-1, -1);

m_Output.ReplaceSel(_T("Y"));

m_Output.SetSel(-1, -1);

m_Output.ReplaceSel(_T("\r"));

m_Output.SetSel(-1, -1);

m_Output.ReplaceSel(_T("\n"));

m_Output.SetSel(-1, -1);

m_Output.ReplaceSel(_T("Z"));
```

The output from the above is:

```
X
Y

Z
```

Why the extra line?!?!

I figure maybe something about the behaviour of Set/ReplaceSel(), but it doesn't insert lines between regular characters in this way, e.g. if I send 'a' followed by 'b' the output is simply "ab" ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The various versions of the RichEdit control are [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as using different characters for paragraph breaks; RichEdit 1.0 used `\r\n`, RichEdit 2.0 is documented as using `\r` and RichEdit 3.0 (and presumably higher) can use both.

What this looks like though is that the control is actually seeing a solitary `\n` as a break as well (i.e. it sounds like it accepts `\r`, `\n` and `\r\n` as all representing a single break). This doesn't match the documentation but then again it wouldn't be the first time Microsoft documentation was somewhat inaccurate.

Internally the control probably doesn't store the actual break character verbatim, so when you feed it a `\r` and then separately a `\n` it isn't able to join them together into a single break.

It sounds like the easiest solution for you would be to filter out `\n` characters rather than sending them to the control. That way all the control will see are the `\r` characters and you'll only end up with a single break in the text.

Comment: Being as I can't be sure '\n' won't at any point be sent alone over the serial link, I'll only ignore when the previous character was '\r'. But good answer, thanks.